# How to get collection product filter by custom attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

i want get all product has "daily = 1", i tryed this code but it get all data product. Please help me.

```
public function getProductCollection(){
      $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
      $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
      $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('daily_offers', '1');
      var_dump($productCollection->getData('daily_offers'));exit;
      return $productCollection;
 }
```

Comment: Your code is correct...Get values using `foreach($productCollection as $product){}`

Answer (score 0):

You wont get you data like this, you need to add a loop to check if you data is getting in collection. like this:

```
public function getProductCollection(){
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('daily_offers', '1');
    foreach($productCollection as $k=>$product){
        echo $product->getData('daily_offers');die;
    }
    var_dump($productCollection->getData('daily_offers'));exit;
    return $productCollection;
}
```

Because attribute is part of the product which is in collection, you cannot directly call it from collection.

Note: If product flat structure is on, then you need to set '`daily_offers`' to **Visible in product listing** from Admin (Store->Attirbutes->Product)

Comment: thanks for answer, but i can't get daily_offers, i set it to yes => value = 1 in product and save. echo = " " and var_dump it = NULL

Comment: Have you select **Visible in product listing** value to **yes**? and run reindexing?

Comment: yes, i set it in product edit page

Comment: Not product edit. **Store->Attribute->Products**, open your required attribute **'daily_offers'**. **Open Storefront Properties** tab, set option **Used in Product Listing** to **Yes**. Run reindex after this

Comment: i set it to yes but it also null

Comment: Also done reindexing?

Comment: use this: `echo $productCollection->getSelect();die;` and check what query you are getting

Comment: There is no attribute daily_offers in query?

Comment: It means either you didn't mark  Used in Product Listing to Yes or you have not reindex

Comment: hmmm, strange, i set to yes and reindex, clean cache